# Removing Cancel Button and "X" From Dialog Box in Swing

Tags: java, swing, dialog

I'm currently working on a chess game for a school project. When you promote a pawn, it opens a dialog box that allows the player to select which piece they would like to promote to. However, when the player clicks "cancel" or "X", then the box simply returns null, and the user cannot promote their piece. I was wondering if I could remove/disable the cancel button and the "X" button. Here is my code:

```
    private String createDialog() {
         hideLabels();
         Object[] options = {"Queen", "Knight", "Bishop", "Rook"};
         String selection = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "What would you like to promote to?, ", "Promote", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, options, options[0]);
         return selection;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a JOptionPane which doesn't give you much control over the functionality you can create your own custom JDialog and add your own components and buttons to the dialog.

You can't remove the close button, but you can prevent the close button from doing anything by adding:

```
dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
```

Or if you really want to use a JOptionPane then check out the section from the Swing tutorial on [Stopping a Dialog From Closing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#stayup) which shows how you check to make sure a valid value has been entered.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think of making my own JDialog, exactly what I needed.